# Does Apple allow different versions of the same game on the App Store tailored for different regions?

Tags: ios, appstore

We are currently in negotiations with a Chinese company to give them the right to re-sell our game in the Asia region.

Now for the Android version they want to sell it trough their website because they want to utilize China specific payment systems. This can be easily achieved by adding an activation system to the app and generating keys for the users who paid.

My problem is with the iOS version. As far as I know there is no way to install an app on iOS outside the app store environment without having a jailbroken phone. Can I just give them the archive of the app from XCode and have them upload it trough their own app store account? Will this cause a problem with Apple that basically the same app will be on the store twice with a different bundle ID?

Comment: Would it be an option to use one app, but have it auto-detect the locale settings of the user and provide different payment options depending on the region?

Comment: @Philipp as far as they told me: For the android version they have to sell it outside the Play store since google does not work with the prefered chineese payment options. For iOS i know nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is probably yes. I’ve had multiple versions of an app on the App Store (one paid, one free).

If you are trying to bypass the App Store in any fashion, the answer is no.

Comment: Technically there is the enterprise distribution, but it's meant for in-house (within a single company) applications. I've built an application that was distributed this way.  However, this would not be a solution for the asker.

Comment: That is correct.